# Reading input from getchar() giving unexpected results

Tags: c, io, scanf, getchar

I have a function which reads PIN from terminal and stores PIN and PIN length in the variables passed. On the first call to the function I get expected PIN and PIN length entered. However, during the second call to this function the first character is omitted.

```
/*
 * Function : read_pin(char *pin,int *pin_len)
 * Description : Read entered PIN and stores PIN in pin and pin length in pin_len
 */
int read_pin(unsigned char *pin,unsigned int *pin_len)
{
    int err = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    char ch;

    fflush(stdout);

    /* Pause to get pin (if removed, input is not read from terminal)*/
    getchar();     // i think,this is causing PROBLEM

    while( ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') )
    {
        pin[*pin_len] = ch;
        (*pin_len)++;
    }

    /* If newline at the end of the pin. You'll have to check that */
    if( pin[*pin_len-1] == '\n' )
    {
        pin[*pin_len-1] = '\0';
    }

    exit:
        return err;
}
```

Calling of this function:

```
printf("\nSelect session : ");
scanf("%d", &option);

printf("\nEnter old PIN: ");
read_pin(old_pin, &old_pin_len); // input: "1234" got: "1234"

fflush(stdout);

printf("\nEnter new PIN: ");
read_pin(new_pin, &new_pin_len); //input: "12345" got: "2345" (1 is omitted)
```

Can someone explain me why I am getting this kind of behaviour and how to fix it?

Comment: Pleas show the call to scanf done before calling read_pin.

Comment: @alk Updated question to show scanf().

Comment: How is `option` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the 1st `getchar()` out of `read_pin()`

```
int read_pin(unsigned char *pin,unsigned int *pin_len)   
{
  int err = EXIT_SUCCESS;
  int ch;  /* getchar() returns int! */

  fflush(stdout);

  /* Pause to get pin (if removed, input is not read from terminal)*/

  while( ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') )
```

and place it right after the `scanf`  call before it calls `read_pin()` the 1st time.

```
  printf("\nSelect session : ");
  scanf("%d", &option);
  getchar();
```

Comment: Now , I am not getting prompt to enter PIN first time, it automatically getting newline and getting exited.

Answer (score 1):

You need `getchar` right after `scanf`

Hence

```
int read_pin(unsigned char *pin,unsigned int *pin_len)
{
    int err = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    char ch;

    fflush(stdout);

   ...........
    getchar();     // Remove this line

    .........

    exit:
        return err;
}
```

Place it right after `scanf`

```
 printf("\nSelect session : ");
  scanf("%d", &option);
  getchar();
```

---

Guess work.

Since `old_pin_len` and `new_pin_len` are acting as indexes initialize them to `0`.

```
int old_pin_len = 0;
int new_pin_len = 0;
```

Comment: Now , I am not getting prompt to enter PIN first time, it automatically getting newline and getting exited.

Comment: @PrateekJoshi You need to show your `main` function also please provide [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

You need to consume the trailing newline character, before reading the 2nd PIN. For example a simple `getcher()` between the two calls of `read_pin()` would produce interesting results for you.

When you input, you hit enter afterwards. That "enter" is the newline character, who looks forward to being consumed.

Comment: "*consume the trailing newline,  before reading the 2nd PIN*" Doesn't  the OP do this here: `while( ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') )`

Comment: But after adding fflush(stdin) between those two read_pin() calls, I am getting the same result. What should I do to fix it because if I remove getchar() before while() loop , I am unable to get PIN.

Comment: @PrateekJoshi: Do not do `fflush(stdin) ` as it causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: alk I see your point. @PrateekJoshi, you need to show us more of your code, show the whole main for example. Something in the order you are calling getchar and scanf has to be the problem. I agree with alk for `fflush()`. It would be nice to have a minimal example, for example what are the lenghts, etc.