# Does if-structure in C affect the value of variable?

Tags: c, char, scanf, getchar

Im trying to write a simple C program to convert the cases of letters

```
char a;
a = getchar();
if(a<=90&&a>=65)
    putchar(a+32);
else if(a<=122&&a>=97)
    putchar(a-32);
else
    putchar(a);
```

When the input is 'A' or 'c',the output is correct;however,when it comes to 'g',the output becomes space and when entering numbers and signals,only get a different output instead of itself.Then I changed the order of ifs,the second problem was solved but the 'g' problem remains.

But I thought the if-structure wouldnt change the value of a;Im quite confused and wonder how.

Comment: Do not use magic numbers. If you want to write down "the character code of the letter A", it is spelled `'A'` in C. Not `65` or anything. Better yet, use built-in functions `islower`, `isupper`, `tolower` and `toupper`.

Comment: Assuming [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoded characters, knowing about them and their values should help. And just don't write code like that! It's bade and undecipherable, and uses [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) and is generally non-portable and (as it turns out) *wrong*. To convert case, use [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) and [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower).

Comment: Oh, and remember that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an **`int`**. This is actually important if you ever want to check for errors or end of file.

Comment: Can't reproduce, see http://ideone.com/pk4zVS

Comment: Having said that, your code [appears to be working with minimal changes](https://ideone.com/zyVojN) (char a needs to be int a so that checking the status of getchar() is possible). There seems to be no problem with the letter g or anything else. Please post a [mcve] which includes the complete buildable program and the offending input.

Comment: Post a complete code example, i.e. code that we can copy directly into an editor.

Comment: Please read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `getchar` reads all symbols including white spaces from the input stream.

Use instead

```
scanf( " %c", &a );
```

Also it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like for example `65` or `32`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char c;

    while ( scanf( " %c", &c ) == 1 )
    {
        if ( 'A' <= c && c <= 'Z' )
        {
            putchar( c | ' ' );
        }
        else if ( 'a' <= c && c <= 'z' )
        {
            putchar( c & ~' ' );
        }
        else
        {
            putchar( c );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter for example

```
A
a
1
G
g
2
```

then the program output will be

```
aA1gG2
```

If to use `getchar` then the approach can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int c;

    while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF )
    {
        if ( 'A' <= c && c <= 'Z' )
        {
            putchar( c | ' ' );
        }
        else if ( 'a' <= c && c <= 'z' )
        {
            putchar( c & ~' ' );
        }
        else if ( isgraph( ( unsigned char )c ) )
        {
            putchar( c );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: c - 'A' + 'a'  and c - 'a' + 'A' are a more self documenting tolower and toupper.

Comment: @mevets I used the approach of the author of the question.

Answer (score 1):

first, for readability, (And to help you to *see* what your code is doing.) replace the magic numbers in your code by using _[ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) `char` values (eg: 'A' instead of `65`) and a *variable* representation of `32`, (distance between cases) in your expressions.
  For example:

```
char a;
a = getchar();    
if(a<=90&&a>=65)
    putchar(a+32);
else if(a<=122&&a>=97)
    putchar(a-32);
```

to

```
char a;
int convert = 32; //distance between cases

a = getchar();
if(a <= 'Z' && a >= 'A')
    putchar(a + convert );
else if(a <= 'z' && a >= 'a')
    putchar(a - convert );
```

And because `getchar()` *[picks up unwanted content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53131468/reading-input-from-getchar-giving-unexpected-results)*, use a more precise way to read your input.

Replace

```
a = getchar();
```

with

```
scanf(" %c", &a);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to do from scratch in portable C. This is because the character *encoding* is left to the implementation. ASCII is common but by no means ubiquitous. Fortunately the C standard library provides the functions you need and the function names render them self-documenting:

```
int a;
a = getchar();    
if (isupper(a)){
    putchar(tolower(a));
} else if (islower(a)){
    putchar(toupper(a));
} else {
    putchar(a);
}
```

Comment: OP is not asking for help translating characters in a portable way. They are asking why the value of `a` appears to change in `if` statements. It does not, in the code shown in the question. They are using some other code and have not provided a reproducible example. This answer does not address the question asked.

Answer (score -3):

From what I understand, the `putchar` takes an `int`, but you give it a `char`.

The same way, `getchar` returns an int, but you assume it to return a `char`.

So you might be wanting to try to change the declaration of `a` from `char` to `int`.